# I deployed my ruby on rails app on VPS, and it gives errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vps

I am using Teamtreehouse's educational tutorials about creating Ruby on Rails app.
So far, I earned  'Designing URLs' badge. (my current knowledge so far)

This application is called 'treebook'.

My treebook is running perfectly on my local PC(Mac).

I don't know why the same app causes errors on VPS server. I set up everything perfectly on my virtual server(serviced by Digital Ocean).
I use **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32bit** with **rails 4.0 and ruby 2.0(the latest version so far)**. You can check its errors here : [http://192.241.210.52:3000/]

I assume this might be caused by the latest ruby version..

Since my local pc uses 'ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386)' and it runs treebook well! :(

Comment: too less information about the error. Paste your log files to get more. Ty.

Comment: Questions should include all the information needed to answer them in the question itself.  The trouble with links is that link-rot sets in, after which the question becomes useless.  And indeed, in this case, the link is no longer any good.

Answer (score 1):

Run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` on your server.

Comment: The reason this is necessary is the error your are getting indicates that the database is not properly set up.  The `db:migrate` command ensures the database on your server has all the tables and columns you've created locally (assuming you've been creating them through rails).

Comment: Awesome! thank you! :D Everything is working perfeclty now!